# How Can I Tell If Meat Has Been Brined?

Tags: chicken, meat, flavor, brining

My wife and I were eating some rotisserie chicken the other night and she commented something to the effect of "I think they brined this because I can taste the seasoning pretty deep in the meat."

I she probably right?  Is there a surefire way to tell if what you're eating has been brined? Perhaps by telltale marks or coloring?

Comment: Shouldn't it taste a lot saltier?

Comment: Actually, this question is also useful before cooking -- if you had a pre-salted (eg, kosher) bird, it'd be pointless to brine it ... I don't know if you could over-brine it.  (I don't think so, unless the solution was too salty, but I coul be wrong)

Comment: Interesting (brief) article here: http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/2005/may/28/foodanddrink.shopping3 . I don't know enough about brining but perhaps they hadn't washed the bird as well as they could.

Comment: Maybe the bird had been injected with marinade? I don't know the correct term for it, but I know you can get syringes that you fill with marinade and use to inject marinade deep into the meat. For industrial purposes I am sure they have machines for it.

Comment: @Henrik - a plausible guess, but I didn't see any puncture marks.  Are you talking about smalling needles?

Comment: @Chad - I have no idea how the industrial machines work, but this method is often used to inject brine into the meat with the specific purpose of selling more water and less meat. For this reason it seems likely that they would try and hide it from the consumer by making the needles as small as possible.

Comment: @Henrik - Ah, true. Thanks for the info. Well, we bought it from a "Chicken Man" cart here in Germany.  At the stand, you pay the same amount for every chicken.  So, if anyone is directly paying extra for water weight rather than meat weight, it would be the stand owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empirically, you could use a salinity meter-- one that is made for checking salt water fish tanks. The only other thing I can think of that would drive seasoning into the meat would be cooking in a pressure cooker. I believe some grocery stores employ such a method on chicken before finishing in a rotisserie. Certain fried chicken chains also deep-fry in a pressure vessel which could yield similar results.

Comment: pressure cookers in fried chicken are to create a certain skin profile and fat structure, it doesn't drive the seasoning into the meat.  Brining is based around a cells osmosis which is why it actually moves the salt deep into the meat.

Comment: Injection, which is very similar to brining, would also move flavor in deep.

Comment: Good point with osmotic pressure @sarge_smith. My thought is that given that the steam in a pressure cooker is applying 15 psi of pressure against the walls of the vessel, one can infer from Pascal's Law that it's also applying 15 psi against the food inside.  That pressure can act on parts of the food that are less dense than water (like fat).

Comment: @kelly You aren't wrong, but sadly, steam doesn't carry flavor very well with it.  What we taste in most spices is basically oils in various configurations, very few of whom are water soluble. In relation to this question, which is dealing with salt, which we know is not steam soluble or the ocean wouldn't be salty and rain would be, that psi isn't going to driving anything anywhere. However, the reason to cook in a pressure cooker is exactly as you said, to let that steam alter the parts that are less dense than water and quickly render and restructure them.

Comment: @Kelly - So I would need a raw, untouched chicken and then a cooked chicken and then I could use the salinity meter... or could I somehow do it with just one cooked chicken. E.g. check the outside of the bird against the inside of the bird, expecting that a brined bird will have an inner salinity very close the the outer salinity?

Comment: @Chad - I suppose either way would work.  Another way would be to remove some undesirable part of the chicken (like the neck) before brining, brine the remaining tasty parts, and then cook everything together.  Comparing measurements of both should give you some empirical data.

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to tell with rotisserie chicken, because of the way it's cooked. Flavors penetrate it very easily due to the whole "impaled on a spit" aspect of the cooking process, and rotisserie style meat is basted often. The best way to find out is to simply ask the cooks.

Comment: You mean that impaling the chicken provides more surface area for juices and seasonings to get to or are you saying that somehow the spit actually gives it a flavor... or something else?

Comment: @chad: Basically it's like flavor injection. Make a bunch of holes in the meat, then baste it, and the flavors will penetrate deeply. You will lose juices though, so it's more suitable to this sort of slow cooking.